# SQLITE3 filter by date

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have an ‘added_at’ column in my database that stores date-times that look like this 2021-06-02T23:39:21.892000+00:00(format: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`). I am trying to perform a select operation and request for rows where the date column is after the given one.
Example:
`SELECT * FROM used_bot WHERE added_at > 2021-08-05T02:13:11.864912+00:00`

That however gives me the following error:

`Exception has occurred: OperationalError unrecognized token: "05T02"`

Can someone please help me and point out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your date time in single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM used_bot WHERE added_at > '2021-08-05T02:13:11.864912+00:00'
```